# unable to mount ntfs partitioned disk -

Tags: mount, files, ntfs, system

I'm unable to mount one of ntfs file system drive since the system got turned of while copying few files to this drive.

I'm getting following message:

> Unable to Mount 94 GB File system  error mouting: mount exited with
>   exit code13: $MFTMirr does not match $MFT record (record 0)
>
> failed to to mount '/dev/sda6':input/output error
>
> NTFS Either inconsistent or there's a hardware fault, or it is a
>   softraid/fakeraid hardware. in the first case run chkdsk/f on Windows
>   and then reboot into windows twice. the usuage of f parameter is very
>   important! If the device is a softraid/fakeraid then first activate it
>   and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/directory,
>   (eg/dev/mapper//nvidia/eahaabcc1) please see the 'dmraid'
>   documentation for more details

This is a partition of my system hard disk, and I can see the same in Gpartition but I get the same error report there also. I've got 1000s of files in this drive, please let me know the ways to recover/mount this drive safely. I don't have a windows system to do any sort of diagnosis.

Appreciate your help and thanks in advance

Mathew Padinjath

Answer (score 2):

NTFS support in Ubuntu is excellent until something goes wrong; because NTFS is basically a Windows filesystem, many of the tools assume a Windows system is available.  It may not be possible to fix it without a Windows system to check from, but according to the first answer to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/193899/how-to-run-chkdsk-if-i-cant-boot-to-windows) it's possible to download a Windows recovery CD that would allow running chkdsk.

It is also worth examining the various ntfs tools installed by default, especially `ntfsls` and `ntfscat`.  These allow one to manually access files without mounting the filesystem, but for thousands of files it's naturally not very practical, and as such should be considered a last resort.

The best solution, in terms of the simplest one with a good chance of success, remains gaining access to a computer with Windows, connecting the hard drive, and running `chkdsk /f` over the partition in question.